# Using selectors for image view in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have around 6 images which i am using as tabs in my application.Its just images and they aren't the tabs that android provides.
So my question is that when i click on a image i want replace the image with a another image so that it can let user know that which tab is selected.
What i am did was creating different xml for this  it in my layout.But its tedious to do so since I can't be creating different xml's for every image.
What i am trying to do now is using  for this but not getting the result.

How is it possible to use for this ?

Comment: Means you have 3 images but you have selected and unselected images for each that making total 6 images.right??

Comment: nope i have 6 different tabs. 2 images for each tab 1 for selected and one for unselected.on selecting a image it should replace the unselected image with selected one

Comment: you are calling different activities on different tabs/images??

Comment: i did that but now i am planning to doing something which normal tabs do,just changing the layout depending on which image is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple.You dont have to make different xml for each image/tab.you just have to make one xml and include this xml in every xml which needs these images..in the xml set only one image as selected and the rest unselected.Suppose for the image1 keep image1 selected and the rest unselected.by clicking image2 will redirect to activity2.In activity2 set image2 selected and the rest unselected and the same for the remaining activities.This way will be the easiest way.Trust me i have implemented this and will help you too.any sort of queries you can ask me.

i have done with 4 images but in your case there will be 6.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        style="@style/toolButton"
        android:background="@drawable/image1"           
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        style="@style/toolButton"
        android:background="@drawable/image2"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        style="@style/toolButton"
        android:background="@drawable/image3"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        style="@style/toolButton"
        android:background="@drawable/image4"
        android:gravity="center"
       />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="toolButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">45dip</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">5</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dip</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: can u provide me with a snippet of your code ? I have been trying this for couple of days now and i am stucked big time

Comment: You only have to set the selected image in the activity of the particular image and rest should be unselected.

Comment: yup i did it.. i set the image in the layout and at run time i just changed the image. i was trying to use selector and was trying to use it.. but now everything is fine.. :) thanks a lot :)

Comment: its my pleasure.i told u na...trust me i have done it before. now enjoy.